# User Levels and OOP architecture

Tags: php, oop, database-design, authentication

I'm developing a login system for the backend.

There will be a number of user levels / permissions to do certain task.

A member can have 1 or more levels.

What are the best architecture to do this?

I came with these solution:

Tables:

```
Group
 - group_id (P)
 - group_name

Group_User
- group_id (F)
- user_id
```

And how link with OOP approach?

OOP Design I have come up with:

```
class User {

private $privateSalt = "Don't Tell Anyone! Q£$£$^$";

public function newAccount($email, $password, $firstName, $lastName) { }

public function login($email = 0, $password = 0) { }

private function _setSession($data) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $data['member_id'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];
}

public function logout() { }

public function isLoggedIn() { }

}
```

It is not necessary to declare User details in the OOP properties because I Have stored in the session? 
Also if user refresh the page, it is recommended to check user $_SESSION['member_id'] against to the database again?

Comment: You say 'levels', but in your example you use 'groups', they're not the same concept. Levels in my opinion would be user rights that strictly increase as your 'level' goes up. When you have groups you can have any permutation of rights assigned to the groups. Can you clarify?

Comment: As a totally unrelated set of tips I would recommend you also include the group names and user names in the data storage (MySQL or whatever) - not just the id's. It will make 'reading' your database a lot easier.

Comment: Another tip is regarding the _setSession function. I know it's private but that signature is just appalling, change it to: `_setSession($id, $email, $firstname)`

Comment: @Frits I didn't realise groups and levels are not the same concept. I guess I meant groups.  Of course I will be storing the group names and user names in the database, mySQL (hince I've tagged database-design).  In regarding to _setSession,  $data is an an array from PDO fetch assoc.

Comment: That's understandable. But I just know that in about 12+ months time you're going to wonder: "what the hell do I put in this function?" :P It's fine to leave it as-is but just make sure you know what you're getting in to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A login system is actually pretty easy to do, *but very difficult to do well*. Implementing  password recovery mecanisms, user account administration for both users and admin, mutliple roles that can be added and edited, all that of course needs to be done in a secure fashion.
Add to that OAuth and OpenID , login systems are one of the most complicated parts of many moderns applications.

I would consider looking at [how others have tackled the problem](http://best-php-scripts.com/login_management.htm), there are libraries and components such as [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) that can help ease the task a lot and make you avoid some basic issues you will encounter.  That being said, DO explore the ideas you have, I mean it's great what you are doing and I am not at all saying this to discourage you. I started on the same exact path you are on, many years ago.

That being said, I have a few questions to ask on your new design. The newAccount function, are those the only parameters needed for that function? You can consider passing objects to functions that require many parameters, that way you can benefit from [type hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). The function login(), why the parameters set to default 0? Are those really default values for that function? At first glance maybe better would be $email=null and $password=null, but can one login with no email/password? If your application logic relies on having those values set, it's ok to have a  function signature  that enforces the logic. I think it's great, though keep up the initiative and be curious.

Happy coding, friend

Comment: Thanks my response my friend. The newAccount function - yes those only parameters needed I needed at the moment but you have made a good a point. I might be expanding parameters in the future, I will definitely look into type hinting, thanks!  The function() function, I have set default to 0 because I will not get an error if parameter is missing from the object like $user->login(). In the login function I did this: if (empty($email) || empty($password)) { return false; }

Comment: +1 for pointing already implemented solutions rather than giving your own

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: I don't know why you'd want to check `$_SESSION['member_id']`

Sessions are stored on the server, so any access goes through code you write. So assuming your code is safe, the data in the session should be safe. Including any permissions you store in them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is not so much a login script but an architecture to manage user permissions.

The login script (and bootstrapping of permissions) should be fairly easy. Stef's link should be helpful for that.

For your permissions architecture with groups a simple user and usergroup with a many-to-many relation (your Group_User) is a very generic solution. Whether it suits your situations, I have no idea, but if your situation is very generic it likely does.

I think this is about as much as I can safely say without knowing your specific situation. If anything, just keep it simple and don't reinvent the wheel.